# Source code for Neo4j graph algo 2.3

Tags: java, graph, neo4j

Where can I get the source code for neo4j graph algo 2.3?

The closest thing I found was the code on this repo:

```
https://github.com/dmontag/neo4j-community
```

But it is too old, at least on the branch master.

Comment: Looking for [this](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/tree/2.3.0)?

Answer (score 1):

That repository is probably something different, then you are looking for.

Here it is:
https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/tree/2.3/community/graph-algo